# Random number between -0.5 and 0.5, efficiently

Tags: javascript

I know there are many method of accomplishing this in JavaScript but what is the most efficient method? Speed is critical as I will need to do this alot upon page load.

Comment: How much is "a lot?", unless you are doing it like a million times I don't think you should be concerned

Answer (score 4):

```
Math.random () - 0.5
```

Not sure how it can be simpler than this.

Comment: Technically that won't give me a number from the domain [-0.5, 0.5] as it can't return 0.5...but I suppose that is not really worth worrying about.

Comment: Next step would be generating your own RNG, but I guess that's beside the point.

Answer (score 0):

@bitoiu is correct

Here is a function if needed for a more general case:

```
function rand(min, max) {
    return (Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}
```

I'm curious as to why this exact requirement is necessary, as handling integers are faster and simpler than floats.